# Unable to connect to cassandra hosted on my VM

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcp, virtualbox, tcpdump

I have a windowns 7 machine, on which I installed Virtual Box, in which I'm running an Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

On that Ubuntu Virtual Machine, I installed cassandra and made it run on the default port 9042. I have configured the port forwarding for virtual Box for that port.

When I try to connect to my cassandra instance using a client inside my VM, it's ok. But if I try to connect to it from my host machine (My actual computer, windows 7), I can't !

When I use tcpdump on my Ubuntu VM, it shows this :

```
14:22:29.340202 IP 10.0.2.2.63128 > 10.0.2.15.9042: Flags [S], seq 606528001, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
14:22:29.340293 IP 10.0.2.15.9042 > 10.0.2.2.63128: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 606528002, win 0, length 0
```

So I suspect the tcp flow [My host machine --> the Ubuntu VM] to be ok, but it seems like the opposite way is not working (the tcp flow Ubuntu VM --> my host machine Windows 7). I also tried to disable the firewall on Windows 7.

Any help on this ?

Comment: If you got answer please update, now I am in your scenario and i need an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ping cassandra on virtualbox guest from windows host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144884/ping-cassandra-on-virtualbox-guest-from-windows-host)

Answer (score 3):

This is a repost of [my answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44170641/622276)

#### Access Cassandra on Guest VM from Host OS

For future reference to myself and others, this worked for me for Cassandra v3.10:

http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/14cpyy7bt8/connect-to-c-instance-inside-virtualbox

Once your Guest VM is provisioned with Cassandra, I had a host only network adapter set with IP 192.168.5.10.

Then had to modify `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` to set:

**From**

```
rpc_address: localhost
```

**To**

```
rpc_address: 192.168.5.10
```

Then run `sudo service cassandra restart` and give it 15 seconds...

Then on the guest VM or on the host the following worked:

```
cqlsh 192.168.5.10
```

Hope that helps someone.

#### Vagrantfile for reference

Note it doesn't work for multiple nodes in a cluster yet

```rb
# Adjustable settings
## Cassandra cluster settings
mem_mb = "3000"
cpu_count = "2"
server_count = 1
network = '192.168.5.'
first_ip = 10

servers = []
seeds = []
cassandra_tokens = []
(0..server_count-1).each do |i|
  name = 'cassandra-node' + (i + 1).to_s
  ip = network + (first_ip + i).to_s
  seeds << ip
  servers << {'name' => name,
              'ip' => ip,
              'provision_script' => "sleep 15; sudo sed -i -e 's/^rpc_address: localhost/rpc_address: #{ip}/g' /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml; sudo service cassandra restart;",
              'initial_token' => 2**127 / server_count * i}
end

# Configure VM server
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  servers.each do |server|

    config.vm.define server['name'] do |x|
      x.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
        v.name = server['name']
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem_mb]
        v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus"  , cpu_count  ]
      end
      x.vm.network :private_network, ip: server['ip']
      x.vm.hostname = server['name']
      x.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
      x.vm.provision "shell", inline: server['provision_script']

    end
  end
end
```

#### provision.sh

```sh
# install Java and a few base packages
add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install vim curl zip unzip git python-pip -y -q

# Java install - adjust if needed
# apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk -y -q
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y -q

# Install Cassandra 
echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 310x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
curl https://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/KEYS | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cassandra -y
sudo service cassandra start
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me. But It did not work for me until I updated the seed provider list. Replaced 127.0.0.1 with guest ip address
`seed_provider:
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "11.9.2.123"`

Answer (score 1):

I enabled a Bridged adapter for the ubuntu vm (guest machine that hosts cassandra). inet addr of the guest vm is 192.168.0.6. My host's (macosx) inet addr is 192.168.0.43 and the virtual interface (vboxnet0) was given an inet address of 192.168.56.1 by VirtualBox when I created a new Host-only network through the global preferences (VirtualBox->Preferences->Network->Host-only Networks). 
I also ensured that the cassandra.yaml file contained the following two properties (besides the 10k others!):

**listen_address**:  192.168.0.6

**rpc_address**: 192.168.0.6

With these settings I was able to connect a java client running on my macosx (host) to a cassandra server running on a ubuntu (guest) vm.

Comment: I changed both the address in cassandra.yml file, now in local machine code which port you used for 'VM Cassandra connecrtivity'?  Like in cassandra.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have networking configured properly in VirtualBox, then check:

the cassandra.yaml configuration, the listen_address should be the IP of your VM, so it is available for remote connections.

More info:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I tried to put the ip adress given by the ifconfig command (the "inet addr" field) but nothing changed. I also tried to put the value I found in the /etc/hostname file, but doesn't work neither.

Comment: Can you SSH into the box from your host?

Comment: Yes I can. That's weird. I also forwarded the port in virtual box but nothing else. Still, I'm able to ssh it using putty from my host windows 7.
It works for ssh but it doesn't for cassandra, nor for Kafka (port 9092).

Comment: Read the answer here on the network options in virtual box and make sure you have that setup properly: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108878/how-to-connect-to-a-guest-vm-from-the-host-system

Comment: Also maybe $ /etc/init.d/iptables stop

Comment: It didn't work. I followed all the steps but the problem is still the same. I'm still able to access ssh, but not cassandra (port 9042) nor kafka (port 9092). When I "tcpdump", it is still the same output.
I also tried to run a webserver on the Ubuntu VM, and I was able to access it via a web browser from my host machine (windows 7). Why does it work for some ports but not the orhers ? I tried to disable the windows 7 firewall, and the Ubuntu VM firewall (using ufw disable, because /etc/init.d/iptables stop didn't work for me), but it was still blocking. Really confusing...

Comment: What was the error when you tried to stop iptables (and obviously you ran as sudo)?

Comment: "bad argument "Stop" "
Yes I ran it as sudo. But appearently, iptables is not a service in Ubuntu. But I followed these post steps : http://serverfault.com/questions/129086/how-to-start-stop-iptables-on-ubuntu
It didn't help